# Is there a way to destroy spike balls?

Tags: terraria

In the dungeon there are spike balls that are annoying! Can I destroy the blocks around it for it to be gone?

Comment: @PanicBomb Agreed, it seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

No, these are "indestructible enemies" as described in the wiki [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Spike_Ball).